# mysql syntax error while creating table

Tags: mysql, sql

Can someone tell why I am getting a Syntax error on line 6

Thanks!

```
CREATE TABLE schools (
    schoolID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    parentID int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    schoolname VARCHAR(199) NOT NULL,  
    active int NOT NULL,
    dateENTERED datetime NOT NULL
),
```

Comment: `','` instead of `';'` is it ok?

Comment: you need to specify a default if not null

Comment: parentID int NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,


active int NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,

Comment: hmm I didnt know that, I will change not null to null then... thank you guys

Comment: I dont that it was the reason, it gave me a syntax error again...

Comment: @Efe -- review this Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5fd81 -- it will work if you remove the comma.

Comment: Also, `parentID` is `INT`, but your default value is a string `'0'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you delete `,` from your last line it should work -

Tested code -

```
CREATE TABLE schools (
        schoolID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
        parentID int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
        schoolname VARCHAR(199) NOT NULL,  
        active int NOT NULL,
        dateENTERED datetime NOT NULL
    );
```

or even this too works(tested in phpmyadmin)

```
CREATE TABLE schools (
        schoolID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
        parentID int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
        schoolname VARCHAR(199) NOT NULL,  
        active int NOT NULL,
        dateENTERED datetime NOT NULL
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that line six is the the dateEnterered, Try something like:

```
dateEntered timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

And yes, change the comma to a semi-colon.